# Disable Multiselection in Go.js record mapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, angular6, angular8

I need to disable Multiselection in the left side table records in Go.js record mapping. Now a node can map with several fields in the right side table data.

I want to restrict left side nodes can use only one mapping to the right side table. But the right side can have multiple from the left table.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you